# Vertical alignment of radio and checkbox with bootstrap 4 beta 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have the text of a radio/checkbox on top (and centered) of the input with the latest version of bootstrap (v4 beta 3). Like this:

[image: What I'd like to achieve]

But it seems like the radio/checkbox itself is in two parts: `.custom-control-label::before` and `.custom-control-label::after` and I can't figure out how to move the input or the text to achieve that behavior

PS Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NBgPRiYRPWYrQwKC94Pt?p=preview) if you want to try

Comment: you just need to re-position the `::before` and `::after`elements :)

Comment: @VilleKoo I've tried it without success...the problem is that for changing its position I need to change the `position` attribute which messes everything up. I can't find a way to consistently have this position no matter how long is the text (I'm not a big css expert :)

Comment: Does this work for you? [plunker fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/mvGKKTAlyF33SEV46EhN?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Bootstrap you need to override positioning of those pseudo-elements

This should be enough:

```
.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-control-label::after {
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: calc(50% - -.25rem)
}
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mvGKKTAlyF33SEV46EhN?p=preview)

**EDIT**

To take multiline labels into consideration, you can do following:

```
.custom-control-label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center
}

.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-control-label::after {
  position: relative;
  order: 0;
}

.custom-control-label::after {
  order: -1;
  /* height of the ::after element */
  transform: translateY(-1rem);
}
```

Comment: Looks great for this particular use case! What about centering the text so the input is right in the middle when the text is long? https://plnkr.co/edit/ZyDYSCNKcRDVUaJ5r3c3?p=preview And what happens when the text has two lines?

Comment: Simply repositionning the input doesn't work in almost all the use cases. I need something more flexible which adapts to long text, multiple lines or even dynamic positioning of the "block" when the window shrinks

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry i didn't take that into consideration. Check out the edited version :)

Comment: This is what I had with a previous beta: https://plnkr.co/edit/elZFCzggtkz2GNVEyNI2?p=preview I'd like to have the same behavior. You can see with multilines or even when there are more checkboxes, the behavior remains consistent

Comment: Wow! It's perfect like this!

Comment: Coolio!! Glad i could help :)

Comment: I spoke to quickly... https://plnkr.co/edit/5HThZOZy468kvEsQUq43?p=preview Select one radio and you'll see that the white circle inside the blue disappeared. Same for the check in the checkbox...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162602/discussion-between-villekoo-and-ncohen).